# Class inheritance in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord

I have a Product table, which has multiple fields like product price, product manufacturer and so on which is common in every item. So I have made a belongs_to relationship with productItem. Every product item has its own specifications. Now I feel the necessity to make few common methods. From the concept of OOP, I have tried to make Parent class Sub class model, where subclass will inherit all the methods of parent. So I have tried doing following:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def check
    ...
  end
end

class ProductItem < Product
  belongs_to :product
end
```

which raises following error:

```
undefined method `some_field_id' for #<ProductItem:0x007f8cac666850>
```

So how can I do parent subclass model in rails?

Comment: Using `STI`,,, read it

Comment: @ArupRakshit: STI won't help here. It seems to me that "product item" is very different from "product". Sharing functionality should be done another way, not through inheritance (mixins, perhaps)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that's true.

Comment: I don't konw if that's what you want, but you could use a `Single Table Inheritance` as in [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) you only need to remove the `belongs_to` in `ProductItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class inheritance **it's not for code sharing**, you should rely on mixins for such a thing. Create a module like this, you can put it in `app/shared/yourmodule.rb`:

```
module Yourmodule

  def dosomething
  end

end

class Product
  include Yourmodule
end

class ProductItem
  include Yourmodule
end

Product.new.dosomething
ProductItem.new.dosomething
```

You can share attributes through STI though, but STI is recommended only if you share **all parent attributes plus a few additional fields**, be careful with it.

STI is simple: add (if you don't have it already) a `type` column to the table you want to inherit from, make it a string and don't set any default and leave it nullable. Now you can just do:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class ProductItem < Product
end
```

You'll be able to access anything from Product

Comment: Why, but one of purposes of inheritance **IS** sharing of functionality. :) Just not very applicable here, but it's a valid approach.

Comment: Mhhh, I've always been highly suggested to use composition/mixins if available when you need to share some code